# What is the reason to use an isolation amplifier?

Tags: isolation

[image]

A PC is connected to a data acquisition card which has single ended channels. One of the channels is outputting a constant DC voltage which can be controlled by a user via a program in the PC.

The output voltage is feeding a VFD. The VFD takes the voltage value and controls the frequency of the AC motor depending on the voltage applied.

There is an isolation amplifier between DAQ analog output and the VFD as in the figure. 
When I measure the analog output of the DAQ and the output of the isolation amplifier with a voltmeter I see the same value.

What might be the reason then for the isolation amplifier?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What might be the reason then for this amplifier?

The possible reason is that your motor controller (Variable frequency drive) is connected to AC mains power and may not have satisfactory protection to offer a signal that controls it. This might mean that the VFD can inject (unintentionally) noise and interference onto its input relative to ground (earth). This may upset the PC DAQ output or indeed cause it to fail or maybe just give the PC a few resets once per year.

There may also be a safety issue - the spec for the isolation device says it has a 250VAC operational isolation and is capable of being "tested" to 3.5kVAC. This sounds to me like it would protect against risk of electric shock and provide decent isolation for noise and ground loops from the VFD.

Comment: u mean for instance if there is a rapid current change or some fault in vfd pc's aq card may be harmed from the high current in case there is no isolation amplifier? do u mean that?

Comment: Multiple grounds on AC circuits can lead to big earth fault currents going thru the daq card.

Comment: i dont understand

Comment: the pc is earthed yeah and the vfd is earthed if the motor smokes it might put ac to the pc via the vfd. Earth is enough to prevent electrocution but no enough to stop a few excess volts zapping the CPU hence isolation is cool.

Answer (score 1):

The VFD used a high voltage AC drive that does not share a common return or ground  with the DAC, thus isoation is needed.

Answer (score -1):

Isolation amplifier has an amplifier and isolator in one package. The reason of using isolation amplifier here is to minimize return loss and amplify the power at the same time

Comment: so u mean it acts as a voltage follower?

Comment: What is return loss?

Comment: no it does not work as a voltage follower

Comment: see this link for return loss http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Return_loss

Comment: but i measure the voltage before and after it is the same value. it looks like it doesnt amplify the voltage.

Comment: re u sure about Return loss  thing? this is not an RF amplifier.

Comment: The only purpose of this amplifier is isolation here nothing else